# How to read pointer to string in my main function, error "expected argument of char* in scanf"

Tags: c, char, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings, allocation

I am a beginner learning C.
I am trying to write two functions, one to allocate a string and the other to insert string1 in string2 from position i.

my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>

//alocation
char * allouerChaine(int n)
{
    char * s =(char*)malloc(n*sizeof(char *));
    if(s!=NULL) 
    return s;
    exit(-1);
}

char * strinsert(char *M, char* T ,int i)
{
   char * temp=allouerChaine(strlen(M)+strlen(T));
    strncpy(temp,M,i);
    temp[i]='\0';
    strcat(temp,T);
    strcat(temp,M+i);
    temp[strlen(M)+strlen(T)]='\0';
    return temp;
}


int main(){
char *M;
char *T;
char*p;
int i;

printf("faites entre la chaine M: ");
scanf("%s",&M);

printf("\nfaites entre la chaine T: ");
scanf("%s",&T);

printf("faites entrer I: ");
scanf("%d",&i);
p=strinsert(M, T ,i);
printf("%s",p);


      return 0;
}
```

when I try with static strings like :

```
 p=strinsert("hello", "ss" ,2);
    printf("%s",p);
```

the code works, which means I don't have a problem with my functions but I do have a problem inside the main.

Comment: You must allocate memory for `char *M;` and `char *T;` (or define arrays instead) in addition to the correct syntax for passing the pointer to `scanf`, which is `scanf("%s", M);`

Comment: Note that `allouerChaine(strlen(M)+strlen(T))` is off: it needs to allow for the string terminator and for additional lengths `i` too. The allocation `malloc(n*sizeof(char *))` is also wrong but not fatally: it should be `malloc(n*sizeof(char))`.

Comment: `char *M;` -> `char M[100];` and `scanf("%s",&M);`  -> `scanf("%s", M);`. Read the chapter dealing with strings in your C learning material. OT: don't use all caps identifiers. Use meaningful variable names. Indent your code properly (like the samples in your learning material).

Comment: Also: `(char*)malloc(n*sizeof(char *))`  -> `malloc(n * sizeof(char))`, or `malloc(n)`. `sizeof char` is 1 by definition. The `(char*)` cast is redundent and useless.

Comment: thank you so much @Weather Vane my program works now.

Comment: Thank you @Jabberwocky, I'll consider your remarks.